# which dual stack server approach is better?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

I wrote two server programs for a Dual stack before implementing in a application.

1. Dual stack server program which can accept both IPv6 and IPv4 clients with a single IPv6 interface. But IPv4 reuest as a mapped IPv6 address.
2. Dual stack server program having two interfaces are listening so as to handle IPv6 and IPv4 clients seperately like IPv6 interface for IPv6 clients and IPv4 interface for IPv4 clients, in which there is no involvement of IPv4 mapped address for IPv4 client request to server.

Both are working fine. But as i need to use only one server model to built my server application. so, which one is preferable or even suggest me if there is any other better model.?

Is *IPv4 mapped IPv6 address* will creates any problems in future.?

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance for the help.
(working in Linux 2.6.9 environment & network programming using C.)

Comment: Do you need to ever target IPv4-only platforms that cannot build with IPv6 code?

Comment: No. our kernel supports both IPv4 and IPv6. We need to communicate IPv4/IPv6 clients and also application need to support stand alone platform also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do everything you need with IPv6 then I think that option 1 is much easier. Your code will be cleaner and maintenance will be easier. You might want to explicitly set the IPV6_V6ONLY flag to 0 in your code if you rely on this in case the default behaviour is changed by the sysadmin.

Comment: Thank you @Sander steffann. My requirement is a Dual stack server is which i have done with a single interface in the 1st model.As you said, first model is easy to maintain. But i have came across a article regerding issues with IPv4 Mapped address in a book "IPv6 Network Programming" By Jun-ichiro itojun Hagino(Google books). In chapter 4, section 4.3, some issues were mentioned that using IPv4 mapped IPv6 address affects security and portability. So, application Security is major,which even costs an additional interface.?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thank you @Sander steffan. But when i had a IPv4 stand alone client (if IPv6 tunneling is not enabled) who try to connect with the same Model-I server which is listening on IPv6 interface.?

Comment: Having the socket listen for both address families has nothing to do with tunnelling. An IPv4 client can just conbect over plain IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the most portable one. OpenBSD for example doesn’t allow the use of incoming IPv4 traffic on IPv6 sockets regardless of the `IPV6_ONLY` option.